# Python import dependencies

Tags: python, opencv, import, python-import, genetic-programming

I am dynamically creating some python code that I want to run inside a wrapper. Here is an overly simplified example.

[wrapper.py]

```
import cv2
img = cv2.imread('pic.png',0)

__import__("fragment")

cv2.imshow('pic',img)
```

[fragment.py]

```
img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_GRAY2BGR)
```

I want the wrapper to set up any imports and variables, then import the fragment which will do stuff (i.e. make the image grayscale) and then do some standardized stuff afterwards (i.e. display image).

The fragments will be changing (genetic algorithm) so I would prefer to keep them separate from the setup which will be constant and will just get make manipulating the fragments more complicated.

When I run the program I get dependency errors on the fragment because cv2 and img are not defined (scope errors). Is there a way to achieve this either with a correction to the method I have used above or with another method?

I expect I might be able to also create the composite of the files in ram and then exec it or write over the fragment with a version of itself that contains all of the needed wrapping, but I wanted to see if there was something cleaner first.

Sincerely, Paul.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The fragments will be changing (genetic algorithm) so I would prefer
>   to keep them separate from the setup which will be constant and will
>   just get make manipulating the fragments more complicated.

Whatever the complexity of the genetic algorithms you implemented in `fragment.py` is, I do not see how importing `cv2` (and eventually more modules) will impact it in a way or an other.

However, I agree with the first part of your statement in that you want to respect the principle of *[separation of concerns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns)* and make your code cleaner.

The solution I see for your problem is to set a configuration file `config.py` in which you set all your imports. But importing `config.py` into other files is useless unless you succeed to make modules such as `cv2` available elsewhere once for all. You can achieve that by *[dynamically importing them](http://www.diveintopython.net/functional_programming/dynamic_import.html)* within `config.py` file:

```
cv2=__import__('cv2')
```

in your main program, `fragment.py` file or whatever module, you can make use of `cv2` by simply running this:

```
import config
config.cv2.imread('pic.png')
```

`import config` ↔ you do not need anymore to run: `import cv2`. This is because this trick renders `cv2` as a global variable available across multiple modules.

The same idea is valid for your other variables such as `img` that you need to declare in your `config.py` file too.

Given these facts, here is my solution for your problem. Note that I am not using classes and functions: I prefer to address your problem straightforwardly and keep things too simple and clear instead.

**Organization of the code:**

The `config.py` file corresponds to your `wrapper.py`:

```
solution/
├── application.py
├── cfg
│   ├── config.py
│   └── __init__.pyc
├── gallery
│   └── pic.png
└── genalgos
    ├── fragment.py
    └── __init__.py
```

**config.py:**

```
# This will make cv2 global and thus you won't need to import it in ./genalgos/fragment.py
# You can use the same idea for all your other imports
cv2=__import__('cv2')
imgc=cv2.imread('./gallery/pic.png') # imgc is global
```

**fragment.py:**

```
# The only import you can not avoid is this one
import cfg.config

# imgs is global
# By importing cfg.config you do not need to import cv2 here
imgf=cfg.config.cv2.cvtColor(cfg.config.imgc,cfg.config.cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
```

**application.py:**

```
import cfg.config
import genalgos.fragment
if __name__=="__main__":

   """
    Display the image 'imgc' as it is in 'cfg/config' file
   """
   cfg.config.cv2.imshow('Pic in BGR',cfg.config.imgc)
   cfg.config.cv2.waitKey(0)
   cfg.config.cv2.destroyAllWindows()

   """
    Display the grascaled image 'imgf' as it is in 'genalgos/fragment' file which
    itself is obtained after transforming imgc of 'cfg/config' file.
   """
   cfg.config.cv2.imshow('PIC Grayscaled',genalgos.fragment.imgf)
   cfg.config.cv2.waitKey(0) # Press any key to exit
   cfg.config.cv2.destroyAllWindows() # Unpaint windows and leave
```

Comment: Hi BEGUERADJ, Thanks for the excellently written answer. This does exactly what I was wanting and it is easy enough to manage the single import in the fragment. No problem with not using classes and functions, I also appreciate clarify over obscurity through best practice. While I was waiting to see if anyone had a better solution I scripted creating new .py files by wrapping each fragment and then executing these, but I believe I'll rewrite to use your method. Thanks again =)